Is there a word for using purposefully incorrect grammar to suit a particular vernacular?
I am thinking of an educated person who knows better purposefully using "me" incorrectly in the subject of a sentence where "I" would be grammatically correct. In doing so they are speaking in the fashion of a vernacular where that would be common.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This sounds like code-switching:

code-switch verb
Linguistics.
intransitive. To shift between languages, or between dialects or registers of a language, within a discourse, esp. in response to a
change in social context. 1964– Source: Oxford English
Dictionary (login required)

If someone asks Who is it? Your answer might be It is I or It’s me—depending on who/m you’re answering. (So that you might have friends, you should probably reserve It is I solely for your teacher of prescriptive grammar.)

Yes. Wikipedia says: "In popular usage and in sociolinguistic study, the term code-switching is frequently used to refer to switching among dialects, styles or registers."
